# MySQL Update doesn't use index when using large quoted integer in WHERE

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a large table (MyISAM) with id as primary key (MySQL version 5.1.54).

When I perform the following query with very large QUOTED integer in WHERE, it doesn't use PK index and runs very very slow (takes several minutes to complete):

```
update BIG_TABLE set some_value=0 where id='10000000000';
```

If I remove quotes, query runs very fast (PK Index is used correctly). This one runs fast:

```
update BIG_TABLE set some_value=0 where id=10000000000;
```

If I don't use large integer value, query runs fast even with quotes:

```
update BIG_TABLE set some_value=0 where id='100';
```

So, it looks like MySQL fails to use index on integer column when value in WHERE can't be converted to integer (value too big for integer). Is there any workaround for this?

I need workaround from MySQL side. Because this query is build by some closed perl library, which can't be changed. All WHERE arguments are quoted automatically and sometimes it happens that Update query is built with very large integer (it's illegal value, so I just expect UPDATE not to update anything).

Right now what happens is that this update query is performed several minutes and it brings the whole system down.

Please note that select is working correctly even with large integers quoted. No problems with this one:

```
select * from BIG_TABLE where id='10000000000';
```

It's something with UPDATE.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of the id column?

Comment: Not sure what you want us to do for you. This isn't the MySQL bug report form. You either need to change the library to not send this query, use the library differently to not send this query, or create some script that watches for slow queries and kills them.

Comment: What is the type of the PK column and what version of MySQL are you using?  10000000000 is only valid as a string value or as a BigInt value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this..

update BIG_TABLE as B1,BIG_TABLE as B2
set B1.some_value=0 
where B2.id='10000000000' AND B1.ID = B2.ID;

Comment: Wow, interesting idea! It works indeed (the update returns immediately telling that 0 rows updated because id wasn't found - which means that index was used correctly and it worked).
But the problem is that this query built by some precompiled perl code, so I can't change it and can't change the query.
So, I hoped I can get some solution on MySQL side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

Well, I didn't find a solution from MySQL side. It looks like some MySQL bug - what I did is changed code to avoid calling Perl library (that builds the query) with large values.

Thanks!